# Room many-to-many with properties in the junction table, how to display list of objects with columns from junction table

Tags: android, android-room

I have a Room database with a many-to-many join, but in that table there are additional properties. Let's say there are Songs, People, and the join has a rating (1-5).

So we have a Song class

```
@Entity
public class Song {

    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @Ignore
    private int rating;

    public Song(String name) { this.name = name;}
    public void setId(@NonNull int id) { this.id = id; }

    @NonNull
    public int getId() { return id; }
    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setRating(int rating) { this.rating = rating; }
    public int getRating() { return this.rating; }
}
```

and a person class:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(@NonNull int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @NonNull
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

and a join class:

```
@Entity (
        primaryKeys = {"personId","songId"},
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(entity=Person.class,parentColumns = "id",childColumns = "personId"),
                @ForeignKey(entity = Song.class,parentColumns = "id",childColumns = "songId")
        })
public class PersonSong {

    private int personId;
    private int songId;
    private int rating=0;

    public PersonSong (int personId, int songId, int rating) {
        this.personId = personId;
        this.songId = songId;
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public int getPersonId() { return this.personId; }
    public int getSongId() { return this.songId; }
    public int getRating() { return this.rating; }
}
```

I want to return LiveData to a RecyclerView to see all the songs and their ratings for a given person. So I need a list of objects showing the song and rating for a given person.

```
@Dao
public interface PersonSongDao {

    @Query("SELECT s.*, ps.rating FROM Song s INNER JOIN PersonSong ps ON s.id=ps.songId WHERE ps.personId=:person ORDER BY s.name")
    LiveData<List<Song>> getAllSongsForPerson(long personId);

}
```

This doesn't seem to be working for me. Points don't seem to fill. I see them in the database, but the number displayed in the RecyclerView is 0 (the initialization number). Also this is somewhat simplistic, both the junction table and the other tables will have more properties. So the Song list with the rating could show singer name as well, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I created a POGO and loaded it up.

```
public class SongAndRating {

    private int songId;
    private String name;
    private int personId;
    private int rating;

... (constructor/getters/setters)
}
```

And loaded it up from the query in the Dao:

```
@Dao
public interface PersonSongDao {

    @Query("SELECT ps.songId, ps.personId, s.name, ps.rating FROM Song s INNER JOIN PersonSong ps ON s.id=ps.songId WHERE ps.personId=:person ORDER BY s.name")
    LiveData<List<SongAndRating>> getAllSongsForPerson(long personId);

}
```